# Python re.search within for-loop to narrow results

Tags: python, regex, search, for-loop, beautifulsoup

To help me learn the basics of python, I'm working on a script that will automatically initiate a helpdesk ticket each time a new RedHat kernel errata is released.

So far I can create a list of all errata, each on it's own line, as a multi-line variable.  I'm hoping to next be able to search within that complete list of errata for just the items that have 'kernel' in the string, and narrowing the variable to just those results is where I'm having problems.  I can essentially find all the matches for 'kernel' but rather than returning the match, it just notes that a match was found.  For example:

```
import re
import datetime
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

errata = 'http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/rhel-server-6-errata.html'

errata_data = urllib.urlopen(errata)
soup = BeautifulSoup(errata_data)

for syn in soup.findAll(attrs={'id' : re.compile("^synopsis")}):
        for line in syn:
                match = re.search("kernel", line, re.MULTILINE)
                print match
```

...results in "none" for the lines that don't match, and a pointer of some sort to denote when it finds a match rather than printing the line that matches:

```
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x3f0ed30>
None
None
None
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that you want to print "the match"? do you want to print the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
    for line in syn:
        match = re.search("kernel", line, re.MULTILINE)
        if match:  # gets rid lines that don't match, which return `None`
            print line
```

`match` is a match object that contains some useful information, such as what position the match occurred at. If you just want to print the matching line, use `print line`.

Comment: Thanks David, this sorted out my issue.

Comment: @user132791: Sure thing. Note that you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to it.